# Ionic - Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ionic.cloudProvider <- ionic.cloud

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-cloud

**The Issue:** I am using Ionic 1 trying to setup push notifications with Ionic Cloud. I get the following error:

```
**Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ionic.cloudProvider <- ionic.cloud <- welcomeCtrl**
ionic.bundle.js:26794 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ionic.cloudProvider <- ionic.cloud <- welcomeCtrl
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/unpr?p0=ionic.cloudProvider%20%3C-%20ionic.cloud%20%3C-%20welcomeCtrl
    at ionic.bundle.js:13438
    at ionic.bundle.js:17788
    at Object.getService [as get] (ionic.bundle.js:17941)
    at ionic.bundle.js:17793
    at getService (ionic.bundle.js:17941)
    at injectionArgs (ionic.bundle.js:17965)
    at Object.instantiate (ionic.bundle.js:18007)
    at $controller (ionic.bundle.js:23412)
    at Object.self.appendViewElement (ionic.bundle.js:59900)
    at Object.render (ionic.bundle.js:57893)(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:26794
```

My app.js:

```
    angular.module('app', [
                'ionic',
                'ionic.cloud',
...
```

I am injecting ionic.cloud.

```
.config(function($ionicConfigProvider, $ionicCloudProvider) {
    // Set tabs always to load on top
    $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('top');

  $ionicCloudProvider.init({
    "core": {
      "app_id": "(my app id was here)"
    },
    "push": {
      "sender_id": "(FCM sender id was here)",
      "pluginConfig": {
        "ios": {
          "badge": true,
          "sound": true
        },
        "android": {
          "iconColor": "#343434"
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I have my config setup properly.

Then in my index.html I have:

```
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <!-- ionic cloud -->
  <script src="lib/ionic.cloud.min.js"></script>
```

And finally in my controller I have:

```
angular.module('app.controllers')
.controller('welcomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'UserService', '$cordovaDevice', '$cordovaCapture','$cordovaFileTransfer', '$cordovaGeolocation', '$location', '$timeout','$state', '$ionicHistory', 'ionic.cloud',
function ($scope, $stateParams, UserService, $cordovaDevice, $cordovaCapture, $cordovaFileTransfer, $cordovaGeolocation, $location,$timeout,$state, $ionicHistory, $ionicPush) {
```

You will see I am inject '`ionic.cloud'` and `$ionicPush`

I have verified in chrome device debug that the resources are there. I followed the Ionic cloud docs to the T, but keep receiving this error.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't it be `$ionicCloud` instead of `$ionicCloudProvider`?

Comment: @AnthonyC Based on this doc, it is $ionicCloudProvider: http://docs.ionic.io/setup.html#installation

Comment: is there a 404 for ionci.cloud?

Comment: @TirthrajBarot I am getting a 200 for the ionic.cloud.min.js. No resources are returning a 404.

Comment: Is the code sample you provided for the start of your controller accurate?  Specifically do you actually list `ionic.cloud` as the name of the injected service?  `ionic.cloud` is the module name, the service you want to inject is `$ionicPush`

Comment: @PaulMichelotti That worked! If you look at the docs for push, they are including 'ionic.cloud' in the section "Injecting Push http://docs.ionic.io/services/push/ . That was confusing me as well but it was in the docs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem here is in your controller you dont have to inject ionic.cloud, it should be

```
angular.module('app.controllers')
.controller('welcomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'UserService', '$cordovaDevice', '$cordovaCapture','$cordovaFileTransfer', 
'$cordovaGeolocation', '$location', '$timeout','$state', '$ionicHistory', '$ionicPush',
function ($scope, $stateParams, UserService, $cordovaDevice, $cordovaCapture, $cordovaFileTransfer, $cordovaGeolocation, 
$location,$timeout,$state, $ionicHistory, $ionicPush) {
```

}

And if your controller is from different module, it should have ionic.cloud injected

```
angular.module('app.controllers',['ionic',
                'ionic.cloud'])
```

Comment: The top section worked. I was following the docs http://docs.ionic.io/services/push/ which listed 'ionic.cloud' in the controller. You are just missing the quotes in the first $ionicPush. Please update and I will accept. Thanks!